# Gulp-less 4.0.1 and Gulp 4.0.0 don't create output css

Tags: gulp, gulp-less

I have Gulp 4.0.0, gulp cli 3.9.1 and gulp-less 4.0.0 installed.
I understand that gulp-less 4.0.1 requires gulp 3.x. 
The question is "How to use less with gulp 4?"
Console and gulp-util doesn't show any bugs, but it looks like less task is ignored.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "quests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "quests",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Toma",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-less": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

Gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require("gulp"); 
var less = require('gulp-less');

gulp.task('less', function () {
    return gulp.src('less/*.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/css"));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch("src/less/*.less").on('change', function(event) {
        console.log(event.path);
        console.log(event.type);
    });
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(['less', 'watch'], function(done) {
    done();
}));
```

Console:

```
[16:53:20] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\quests\gulpfile.js
[16:53:20] Starting 'default'...
[16:53:20] Starting 'less'...
[16:53:21] Finished 'less' after 45 ms
[16:53:21] Starting 'watch'...
```

Comment: maybe you shoud use `gulp.src('less/**/*.less')` and `gulp.watch("src/less/**/*.less")`?.. It's hard to say smth, you didn't provide your project structure...

Comment: @Arfeo i tried, it didn't help :\ structure is the simpliest: src/less/style.less

Comment: stop. then try `gulp.src('src/**/*.less')`. It tries to find less files in `./less` directory, which does not exist.

Comment: @Arfeo, thank you! It helped, but now i got three directories in dist dir: less, node_modules, src. Is it okay? o_O It's my first gulp project

Comment: Try to drop `dist` dir and run gulp task again. Is this happening again?

Comment: @Arfeo i found solution: `gulp.src('src/less/*.less')` and now my topic looks so stupid :D Thank you!

Comment: Good news. Nevertheless, I'm afraid that you've got `node_modules` dir inside your `src`. It's wrong if it's true.

Comment: @Arfeo no, it was because of typo in path :) now everything is okay, thanks to you

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, коллега! )